# WR91700 datasheet or pinout

Tags: pcb, datasheet, replacement

After several attempts trying to find out the datasheet or pinout of WR917O0 IC, I only have found a service manual of PSR-S710-S910 Yamaha workstations. The IC is included in the list of components without further information.

Does anyone know about this IC?

Comment: Which IC is that then? Custom Yamaha sound chipset?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be a sound chipset, but I'm not 100% sure.